# Can (or how) can a real keyboard, mouse and monitor be connected to the Microsoft Surface Go?

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, microsoft-surface

From the one review I have read so far, the Microsoft Surface Go does not have a video port and only has one "odd shaped" USB port.

Hence is it possible to set it up as a “real” computer with a large monitor, real keyboard, and mouse?

Comment: What do you mean by _"odd shaped" USB port_?

Comment: @gronostaj it does not look like a normal USB port on the photo.

Comment: It's [USB type C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C), a newer connector usually (but not necessarily) implementing USB 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible to set up as a desktop computer (i.e. with mouse, keyboard and screen).

To do that you will need a **USB C** to **HDMI / Displayport / VGA and USB A** adapter or docking station.

If you google for something like "**usb c to displayport and usb a**" I'm sure you'll find a few different products.

Since the tablet you've referenced is new, maybe wait to see if a reviewer recommends a specific adapter, hub, or docking station, which you can take as a reference for what should work.

Comment: It is very likely the Surface Go will be compatible with the current [Surface docking station](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-dock/8qrh2npz0s0p?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab) (but can't guarantee it) and/or get it's own.  Since it has a USB 3.1 Gen 2 port, it's very likely, you can use any USB 3.1 docking station on the market.  I just realized your answer is based on the fact you are suggesting a docking station.  Since there is a docking station specifically designed for the Surface, I will keep my comment, might be useful to somebody